# Copy array of multiple files with globbed extensions, in bash 3.2

Tags: bash, quoting, wildcards

I've found bits and pieces of each of the things I want to do across the Web, but nothing exactly fits my use case.

I'm trying to write a script that copies multiple specific files to a directory on the Desktop, as well as files with a certain file extension. It also has to run on bash 3.2.

This line is the one that trips me up. I realize it probably has to do something with pattern matching, order, expansion and globbing.

```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

  declare -a backup_files=(*.{id,nsf}, "desktop8.ndk", "archive", "user.dic");
  declare -a notes_data_directory=~/Library/Application\ Support/IBM\ Notes\ Data/;
  declare -a notes_backup_directory=~/Desktop/Notes\ Backup;

  mkdir "$notes_backup_directory";
  cd "$notes_data_directory";

  for i in "${backup_files[@]}"
  do
    cp -nipvR "$notes_data_directory$i" "$notes_backup_directory";

    # Also tried this
    # find "$notes_data_directory""$i" -exec cp -nipvR {} "$notes_backup_directory" \;
  done

  cd -
```

When I `echo "$backup_files"` this is what I get:

`*.{id,nsf},
desktop8.ndk,
user.dic`

I'm sure it has to do with syntax. I just don't know where.

Comment: Remove double quotes from first element `*.{id,nsf}`. By putting quotes around this pattern you do not ask shell for globbing, while this is your intention (if I correctly understood the question). Secondly, remove delimeter `,` unless you want it as a part of array elements.

Comment: I'll add, if you wish to see the contents of the array then you should try `echo ${backup_files[@]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting quotes around some text disables expansions such as wildcards expansion and brace expansion. A logical way to remember this is that they produce a list of words, but contexts such as quotes ensure that the content is a single word.

Furthermore you have spurious commas. In a shell script, words are separated by spaces.

```
declare -a backup_files=(*.{id,nsf} "desktop8.ndk" "user.dic")
```

You can write this as

```
backup_files=(*.{id,nsf} "desktop8.ndk" "user.dic")
```

unless you also wanted to declare `backup_files` as a local variable in a function.

Note that if one of the patterns doesn't match any file, it will be left unexpanded. For example, in an empty directory, you'll end up with the four elements `*.id`, `*.nsf`, `desktop8.ndk` and `user.dic`. If you're only going to pass these to `rm -f`, it doesn't matter. More generally, you can cope with that by checking whether each element is an existing file when processing, e.g.

```
for x in "${backup_files[@]}"; do
  if [[ ! -e "$x" ]]; then continue; fi
  …
done
```

(Incidentally, note that accessing the elements of an array is an exception to the rule that a quoted string results in a word rather than a list of words. With array expansion, the double quotes ensure that *each elements* ends up as a single word, rather than undergoing pattern matching and word splitting. This, including variants such as `"$@"`, is the only exception.)

Alternatively, you can set the `nullglob` option to make pattern matching result in an empty list when it matches no files.

```
shopt -s nullglob
backup_files=(*.{id,nsf} "desktop8.ndk" "archive" "user.dic")
```

Then the array will only contain existing `.id` and `.nsf` files, but it will contain `desktop8.ndk` and `user.dic` no matter what. You can arrange to exclude these files if they don't exist by making them a pattern as well.

```
shopt -s nullglob
backup_files=(*.{id,nsf} desktop8.nd[k] archiv[e] user.di[c])
```

Note that the braces and wildcard are expanded when the array is defined. Thus the patterns match files in the current directory. Your script is doing something strange and probably unintended: you're gathering names of files in the current directory, and copying identically-named files from a different directory `$notes_data_directory`. If you want to match files in a different directory, you need to say so.

```
notes_data_directory=~/Library/Application\ Support/IBM\ Notes\ Data/
notes_backup_directory=~/Desktop/Notes\ Backup
backup_files=("$notes_data_directory/"*.{id,nsf} "$notes_data_directory/desktop8.ndk" "$notes_data_directory/archive" "$notes_data_directory/user.dic")
for i in "${backup_files[@]}"
do
  cp -nipvR "$i" "$notes_backup_directory"
done
```

You can use brace expansion to shorten the definition of `backup_files`:

```
backup_files=("$notes_data_directory/"{*.{id,nsf},desktop8.ndk,archive,user.dic})
```

Alternatively, switch to the directory before copying.

```
notes_data_directory=~/Library/Application\ Support/IBM\ Notes\ Data/
notes_backup_directory=~/Desktop/Notes\ Backup
cd "$notes_data_directory"
shopt -s nullglob
backup_files=(*.{id,nsf} desktop8.nd[k] archiv[e] user.di[c])
for i in "${backup_files[@]}"
do
  cp -nipvR "$i" "$notes_backup_directory"
done
```

Yet another approach is to store a list of patterns in the array, and use the variable unquoted in order to expand the patterns. Note that the brace expansion needs to take place at the time the source code line is parsed, whereas the wildcards need to be stored unexpanded in the array. If there's any whitespace in the pattern, it needs to be quoted; getting this right is slightly tricky. I don't recommend this approach, it's hard to follow. Since a pattern may or may not end up matching a file, but `cp` requires at least one source file, you need to handle the case where the pattern matches zero file separately.

```
notes_data_directory=~/Library/Application\ Support/IBM\ Notes\ Data/
notes_backup_directory=~/Desktop/Notes\ Backup
backup_patterns=(\*.{id,nsf} "desktop8.nd[k]" "archiv[e]" "user.di[c]")
# equivalent to backup_patterns=("*.id" "*.nsf" "desktop8.nd[k]" "archiv[e]" "user.di[c]")
shopt -s nullglob
for i in "${backup_patterns[@]}"
do
  files=("$notes_data_directory/"$i)
  if [[ ${#files[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
    cp -nipvR "${files[@]}" "$notes_backup_directory"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Fascinating. Everyone so far agrees to remove the double quotes and commas. The difference between your answer and @jimmij's is the `declare -a` statement. While neither one fixes the issue, the presence of `declare -a` affects the output.

**script**     

`declare -a backup_files=(*.{id,nsf} "desktop8.ndk" "user.dic"); 
echo $backup_files`

**shell**     

`$ . ./notes-backup.sh  
*.id`

`$ . ./notes-backup.sh 
*.nsf`

Comment: @KevinSuttle I still don't know what you're trying to say here.

Comment: TL;DR: while `declare -a` changes the output, neither answer actually works. One echoes `*.id`, the other `*.nsf`.

Comment: @KevinSuttle What you posted in your comment isn't complete code, is broken because it lacks double quotes when you use `backup_files` (it should be `echo "${backup_files[@]}"`), and you aren't saying whether there are files matching the patterns. You also didn't provide the rest of the code. Nothing that you show uses any script argument, so if passing different arguments produces different results, it's obviously due to something you didn't show. Edit your question to post your whole script — but you may have a different problem requiring a new question.

Comment: No, I posted what code I had, and all of the output. SO doesn't support carriage returns, and by extension, code blocks in comments, so it may have been harder to read.

Comment: @KevinSuttle So at least post your whole script in the question. You talk about output, but none of the code you show produces any output. A whole bash script starts with `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. If you're sourcing the script in another script, post the other script as well. Tell us what files are present in the current directory as well.

Comment: Ok, I added the full script for context.

Comment: @KevinSuttle So what's wrong after you apply the corrections in my answer? I don't see any other error in the current version of the question.

Comment: Have you tried it? It doesn't work. It copies one file, user.dic. The other files are definitely there. https://gist.github.com/kevinSuttle/f7ffd6f3b0750e2ed5be

Comment: Removed the double quotes and commas, and that works for the named files, not the *id and *.nsf patterns. https://gist.github.com/kevinSuttle/f7ffd6f3b0750e2ed5be

Comment: @KevinSuttle Ok, I think I got it. You're matching files in the current directory, but, presumably, you want files in a different directory. See my edit.

Comment: YES. This was it. Thank you so much for being so thorough!